# Preview figures in MS Word without rendering

Tags: r, ggplot2, quarto

Is there a way to preview a figure (for example a plot created with ggplot) from a quarto code chunk in Word without rendering the entire document?

The equivalent can be done with a table created using the flextable package:

```
ft <- flextable(airquality[ sample.int(10),])
print(ft, preview = "docx")
```

The above renders just the table to a temporary Word doc - I would like to do the same with figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of any default option to do so, but you could write yourself a custom function to achieve that by mimicking the way `print.flextable` works for `docx` output.

The code below is basically a copy & paste from `print.flextable` where I replaced `body_add_flextable` by `body_add_gg`:

```
library(ggplot2)

gg2docx <- function(x, ...) {
  doc <- officer::read_docx()
  doc <- officer::body_add_gg(doc, value = x, ...)
  file_out <- print(doc, target = tempfile(fileext = ".docx"))
  browseURL(file_out)  
} 

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

gg2docx(gg, width = 6, height = 4)
```

[image]